# Why won't my .vue file find the JSON I'm trying to pass it?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

Can anyone look through this snippet of code and tell me why I'm getting this error ?

> json is undefined

(in reference to test: json below).

I've defined it, directed it to the correct component, and the json is being fetched correctly (i can see the entire object in the console). So why can't my component display it? Thanks in advance to any vuejs users who can help me with this.

The .vue file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      test: json
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

the .js file:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    json: {}
  }),
  created: function () {
    apigClient.invokeApi(apiPathParams, apiPathTemplate, apiMethod, apiAdditionalParams, apiBody).then((response) => {
      this.json = response
      console.log(this.json)
    })
  router,
  template: '<app/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to pass that `json` variable as `props` or define it before `export default{ ...`

in the `main.js` send that json to child component as follow :

```
     ...
     template: '<app :json="json"/>'
     ...
```

in the child component receive it like:

```
      export default {
       props:["json"],
        name: 'app',
         data () {
         return {
              test: this.json
       }
     }
    }
```